# Help with creating mixed model with multiple within-subject variables

Tags: mixed-model

I have experiment that looks somewhat like that. Example dataset:

```
df<- data.frame(
  c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
  c("pre","pre","post","post","pre","pre","post","post","pre","pre","post","post"),
  c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B"),
  c(3,4,5,2,4,1,3,5,6,3,2,9))
colnames(df)<-c("subject","time","group","var")
```

I have couple of subjects (variable `subject`, 3 in this example). Each of them have quantitative measurements `var` before and after event (`time` variable). But at the same time in each time point, each subject have two separate measurements A and B like in variable `group`.

I'm trying to model differences between group, changes in time, and also taking in account multiple measurements from each subject (though actual difference between subjects don't interest me).

I assume i have to construct a mixed model, I looked through couple of books but it only got me more confused (nested ? grouped random effect? in what combination ?).

I would be grateful for helping me out with either helping me out with this model, or suggesting other approach to this problem.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking here. Do you want to know which software can help you do this, or which statistical test to use? Meanwhile, try looking at the `lme4` package, in particular the `lmer` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in modeling the differences between group and pre and post event (time) then those should be fixed effects in your model. As you are not interested in subject specifically, but different individuals cause variation in your response variable, it would be a great candidate for a random effect intercept (1|subject). If you really only have three (although maybe that was just the example you used), that is not really enough levels to include it as a random effect and you should include it as a fixed effect instead.

Here is a great discussion on fixed and random effects: https://dynamicecology.wordpress.com/2015/11/04/is-it-a-fixed-or-random-effect/ which includes a decision tree for choosing between whether to include something as fixed or random.

Answer (score 0):

If you are mainly interested in differences in time and Group, those variables should be treated as fixed effects. As you want to take into account, "multiple measurements from each subject ", I suggest to allow these effects to vary across subjects. This mean that you also model them as random effects:

```
library("lme4")
mod <- lmer(var ~ 1 + time +  group + (1 +  time +  group|subject), data = df)
```